# Sympy: how to factor constants out of sum?

Tags: python, sympy

As a Sympy newbie, I was trying to learn how to use it by test-driving it on a simple case (simple least squares fit to a straight line). This is what I have as result of previous calculations (next line is an **output** from iPython):

```
Sum(2*a*x(i)**2, (i, 1, N)) + Sum(2*b*x(i), (i, 1, N)) + Sum(-2*x(i)**2, (i, 1, N))
```

I would now like Sympy to get the constants (such as 2*a, 2*b and -2) **out of the summations** as multiplicative factors, but I don't know how to achieve that. I've tried with collect, factor, and other functions to no avail. Would you be so kind as to point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same @smichr here with basically the same solution:

```
def cSum(s):
  con, dep = factor_terms(s.function.as_independent(*s.variables))
  return con*Sum(dep, *s.args[1:])

var('a b x N i')
eq = Sum(2*a*x(i)**2, (i, 1, N)) + Sum(2*b*x(i), (i, 1, N)) + \
     Sum(-2*x(i)**2, (i, 1, N))
>>> pprint(eq.replace(lambda s: isinstance(s, Sum), lambda s: cSum(s)))
      N                 N              N
     ___               __             ___
     \  `              \ `            \  `
2*a*  \    2    + 2*b*  )   x(i) - 2*  \    2
      /   x (i)        /_,             /   x (i)
     /__,             i = 1           /__,
    i = 1                            i = 1
```

UPDATE:

Current versions of SymPy give:

```py
>>> factor_terms(eq)
2*(a*Sum(x(i)**2, (i, 1, N)) + b*Sum(x(i), (i, 1, N)) - Sum(x(i)**2, (i, 1, N)))
```

Comment: I'm about to pick yours as the answer; however, I'm still curious as to why this is not a built-in feature. I'm not complaining here: It seems to be something that can be implemented by a rather simple rule, isn't it? or is there some complexity underneath that it's eluding me?

Comment: Part of the issue is in finding the place that this transformation belongs or finding a name for it that makes sense for a general expression. For example, your expression is an Add in which there are objects (Sums) that need the transformation -- so what should that transformation be called. Perhaps a good place for this is in some sort of basic expansion for Sum objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answers to both my questions!

Comment: I see that I already opened an issue (and now added a suggestion regarding expansion) at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7902. Now someone that also believes this is important needs to take action.

Comment: Thanks! My second question had that in mind; if a simple solution is available, I was planning on opening an issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7902) it seems that there isn't currently any method to factor out the terms which are independent of the summation. Perhaps this will be implemented in future releases of SymPy.

For a single `Sum` term, @smichr (on that GitHub page) suggests a workaround as follows:

```
s = Sum(2*a*x(i)**2, (i, 1, N)) # your first Sum term 
con, dep = factor_terms(s.function.as_independent(*s.variables));
factored_s = con*Sum(dep, *s.args[1:])
```

Which produces the term `factored_s` as:

```
2*a*Sum(x(i)**2, (i, 1, N))
```

For your case of an expression with several `Sum` terms, you could split them into a list with `as_ordered_terms()`, run the workaround method on each one and then add them back together into a single expression.